# Efficient way to compare VERY LARGE NUMBER OF VALUES php

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, large-data

hi
i am to compare very large number of values, i used arrays, but run out of memory. the values in arrays are around 5000000, and for every values again a loop of 5000000 will execute. in short 5000000 x 5000000 cycles will be executed.

what i am doing is simply running two loops. please let me know some efficient way to do this as this program stops because of the memory.

```
for($k=0;$k<sizeof($pid);$k++) // size of $pid = 5000000
{
$out =0;
        for ($m=0;$m<sizeof($outid);$m++) // size of $out 5000000
        {
                    if ($pid[$k] == $out[$m])
                    {
                            $out ++;
                    }

        }
}
```

Comment: If you need to execute 25,000 billion iterations, you don't use PHP!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I think if you explain the problem a bit more, you'll probably get some more helpful answers...

Comment: Alternatively, you change your algorithm so that isn't O(N^2) time complexity.  If all you're doing is finding the number of common elements in each array, then there are algorithms that run in O(N log N).

Comment: I agree with @Oli. What are you trying to accomplish? This can be done with other programming languages more efficiently, as PHP wasn't made for this...

Comment: @ Ben
i want to compare the values, if the values in pid appear in outid then increase value of pid as many times as many time the id appears in outid.

Comment: @Oli
any algorithm that can help me, as i am new to this :(

Comment: don't know about memory, but  spl data structures has much better performance than arrays , you can try SplFixedArray for example

Comment: Never mind that on a 32bit PHP install, it's going to overflow the int limit on $out long before it hits the end of the outer loop.

Comment: @phihag
Thanks a lot dear for guiding me. actually i am new to all this thats why have lots of problems.

Comment: @Marc B
i m using 64 bit system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm complexity can be a complex subject for most of VB and PHP programmers - it is not trivial.

### Approach 1

Lets say you find a way to use your `O(n^2)` approach, and lets say your computer can execute 1000000 comparisons in 1 second, and you start the loop now `2:04:45 pm EEST  |  Wednesday, June 23, 2010`, then the loop would end in `6:58:05 am EET  |  Monday, January 23, 2012`.

I'm not an expert in PHP, but I'm certain that page has a time limit under what it must be served or page timeout exception is throw. That limit can be 30s, 90s or what ever you define it, but your required timelimit for this loop is silly.

### Approach 2

You decide to sort the array, this action takes `O(n log n)` for both arrays, and `O(n log n)` to compare. This will make the total time to be around `3 * O(n log n)`, that's just `100.5 seconds`. Or `33.49 seconds`, if arrays are presorted.

I would pick the **Approach 2**, if I was you.

If you are uncertain, how to sort array, then ask a new question and describe your data. In short, you need a custom comparator for your data instances. To compare in `O(n log n)` you can not use linear compare, but need a efficient deep compare function, usually built in language default libraries. If you can not find it or do not know how to use it, then ask another question.

Comment: I don't really see the point of general statements like "Algorithm complexity can be a complex subject for most of VB and PHP programmers". Especially when no one mentions VB ; it seems a bit gratuitous.

Answer (score 3):

If you could sort both lists you would only have to look at all of each list once because you could have an index for the first list and an index for the second list.  If the element at the first index is less then the element at the second index, increase the first index, otherwise increase the second index.  Then you just keep track of how many elements are equal as you pass over them.

Comment: this is not that simple, the pids are unique but the outids are duplicates, and the formate is also complex its like 01.2.14.1234

Comment: As long as only one list has duplicates, that's not an issue if you make sure to always increase the index of the list with duplicates when the values are equal in both lists.  The complexity of the format is not important so long as both lists can be sorted the same way.

Answer (score 0):

you can try array-intersect function http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php, it's C based  and should work more optimized